# android: fragments are displayed over each other

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to add two fragments on one activity.
The problem is that the fragments are displayed over each other instead of under each other.

My code:

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/sample_content_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/sample_content_fragment2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
  base.OnCreate(bundle);

  SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

  SlidingTabsFragment fragment = new SlidingTabsFragment();
  MediaPlayerFragment mpFragment = new MediaPlayerFragment();

  FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

  transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
  transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.sample_content_fragment2, mpFragment);

  transaction.Commit();
}
```

and

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.mediaplayer, container, false);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:id="@+id/layout_select_course"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="0.5">
         <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/sample_content_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   </RelativeLayout>

   <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/sample_content_fragment2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I can't add the "<LinearLayout/> at the end of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping out the `RelativeLayout` with a `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/sample_content_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/sample_content_fragment2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @beginner You need to also make the `layout_height` attribute in the  parent element in your fragment views either `wrap_content` or use a smaller height than the screen

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
It should make your layouts take half of the screen each. Alternatively you can play with weights or make only one with weight and other with wrap_content without weight. Just make sure the fragments layout isn't too big so the other one fits.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sample_content_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sample_content_fragment2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```